# How to read next characters if it the given string is found inside a file using bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file as below  (file name is /document/test)

```
  Filename:  
  Description:  
  Version:  1.0
  Created:  
  Revision:  none
  Compiler:  gcc
   Author:   (), 
   Company:
```

I want to write a bash script that would display the version number (here in this example 1.0)

I've tried this

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if grep -q Version /Documents/test; then
    echo "string found"
else
    echo "not found"        
fi
```

it says string is found, but I need the version number if the given string is found

Comment: Bei using `v=$( command ...)`, the standard output of _command_ is stored into the variable `v`. You could store the line containing the version number into a variable, and then use regular expression matching to extract the version number from the variable.

Answer (score 3):

You could use awk to find all rows whose first word is `Version:`, then output their second word:

```bash
awk '$1 == "Version:" {print $2}' /Documents/test
```

```
1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to do these in regex way:

```
grep 'Version:' /Documents/test | grep -Eo '([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)'
```

```
1.0
```

- `-E` : extended regular expression.
- `-o` : return only matched part.

thus, you can even change regex to adjust version pattern you want.

e.g.

```
# only match version 1.x
grep 'Version:' /Documents/test | grep -Eo '(1\.[0-9]+)'
```